# String comparison in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Does SQL Server 2008 have a string comparison method that checks which string is supposed to come first (ex 'abc' comes before 'abd' etc)? I need to do a <= comparison.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<=` works fine. The problem you're having is that you're expecting numeric sorting out of strings. That doesn't work without special handling.

**String Sorting**

a1 - a10 strings sort in this order:

```
a1
a10
a2
a3
a4
...
```

This is because both a1 and a10 start with "a1".

Since they're strings the numeric values are irrelevant. Look what happens when we substitute a-z for 0-9:

```
ab
aba
ac
ad
ae
```

Can you see now why you're getting the results you are? In a dictionary, aba comes before ac, and a10 comes before a2.

To solve your problem it's best to split your column into two: one char and one a number. Some unpleasant expressions can get the right sort order for you, but it's a much worse solution unless you have absolutely no choice.

Here's one way. It may not suit or there may be a more efficient way, but I don't know what all your data is like.

```
SELECT
FROM Table
WHERE
   Col LIKE 'a%'
   AND Substring(Col, Convert(int, PatIndex('%[^a-z]%', Col + '0'), 1000)) <= 10
```

If the alpha part is always one character you can do it more simply. If the numbers can have letters after them then more twiddling is needed.

You could also try a derived table that splits the column into its separate alpha and numeric parts, then put conditions in the outer query.

**Collation**

Be aware each string and char-based column has a collation setting that determines what letters are sorted together (mostly for case and accents) and this can change the results of an inequality operation.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE Value <= 'abc'

SELECT CASE WHEN Value <= 'abc' COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS_KS_WS THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM Table
```

The collation I used there is case sensitive, accent sensitive.

You can see all the collations available to you like so:

```
SELECT *
FROM ::fn_helpcollations()
```

Comment: Is there some sort of "hash" function that will generate a unique number from the string so I can compare that instead of the string?

Answer (score 5):

In what context?  `<=` works in a SELECT statement.

Comment: Agreed.  The list of various string collations is given at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250.aspx

Comment: SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT 'a1' AS col1 UNION SELECT 'a2' UNION SELECT 'a3' UNION SELECT 'a10' UNION SELECT 'test'
) a WHERE col1 <= 'a10'; yields 'a1' and 'a10' only.

Comment: @mwok - That is because `a2` and `a3`, alphabetically, come after `a10`. If you want to the system to evaluate the numeric value the structure of the string must be consistent. Do they always start with a single character?